# How to localize amp-facebook-like

Tags: amp-html

There is nice component amp-facebook-like which can have an optional 
attribute data-action="recommend|like" but how this label could be localized?
For example in data-action="Teilen"

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-facebook-like#data-action-(optional)), I think it is not possible to do that. Since it was specified that:

> The verb to display on the button. Can be either `like` or
>   `recommend`. The default is `like`.

Comment: well I know that just "like" or "recommend" could be set as attribute value just how can we localize that button text?

Comment: for now I am using `<amp-social-share type="facebook" 
                              width="74"
                              height="28"
                              data-param-app_id="xxxx"
                              class="facebook-share"
                              data-param-url="@HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Url.ToString())"></amp-social-share>` where class="facebook-share" set background Image with localized text.